# Hide the comments panel in WP custom post types

Tags: wordpress, comments, admin, custom-post-type

Is there a way I can hide the comments panel in my custom post type and still allow people to comment? Because I noticed that for the *Post* post type the comment panel is hidden and yet users can post comments to it.

When creating a custom post type in wordpress, I always add

```
'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'comments'),
```

which enables comments the post type, however, there always seems to be a comment panel at the bottom of the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the left top corner below the admin bar there is a `screen options` button.
On it are checkboxes which hide and shows part of the UI.

You can hide your comment pannel on the add/edit pages.
These settings are saved per user. So if you turn it off, an other user will still have it.

Comment: Is there a way to set a default setting where it's hidden? I don't really mind that I can see the panel, it's more of an *ethical programmatic crisis* (or something) where if WP can do then so can all other WP programmers. :)

Comment: This might help, it does require you to enter a phpmyadmin: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/same-screen-options-for-all-users?replies=10